# Expl3 - Fill a tabularray in xskakloop

Tags: expl3, tabularray, xskak

I would like to fill a tabularray `tblr` or `longtblr` environment using the `\xskakloop` command of the xskak package.

I would like to use expl3 if possible. I have tried looking into the xskak source code but I still have no idea if it is at least compatible with expl3.

Using the `\ExplSyntaxOn` command inside the `\xskakloop` argument would result in unexpected results as far as I can tell. I tried to redefine a `\xskakloop` equivalent in expl3 but I'm no tex wizard.
The amount of documentation that I should consult to achieve this basic result for an hobby project that I do in my limited time is frankly overwhelming.

I would like to achieve something on the line of this if possible:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage[l2tabu]{nag}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LSBC4, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC4}%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame
\hidemoves{1.e4 f6, 2.d4 g5, 3.Qh5#}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[c] X[c] X[c] @{}}}
    \xskakloop{%
        {
            \chessboard[tinyboard, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
            \\
            \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}%
        }
        % maybe putting this inside a command or something
        \ExplSyntaxOn
        \int_if_zero:nTF {\int_mod:nn {(\xskakget{movenr} - 1) * 2 + (\str_if_eq:eeTF {\xskakget{player}} {w} {1} {2})}{3}}
        { \\ }
        { & }
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    }
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Edit:

For context, the expl3 section uses the `\xskakget{movenr}` and `\xskakget{player}` commands to calculate the loop iteration number.
If the iteration number is multiple of the table columns number it should add a new row (possibly it should not add a new row for the last iteration), else it should start a new column.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I realized this will only works for games starting from the first move.
I guess a variable to actually count the iteration is actually required.

Comment: I've tidied up by deleting my comments. You might want to do the same to keep the system happy :). (It doesn't like too many comments.)

Answer (score 4):

At first, you can not switch to expl3 syntax in the middle of an argument. The catcodes are already fixed and `\ExplSyntaxOn` can't change them anymore.

At second loops in tabulars are generally difficult, as every cell is a group and you often loose definitions (and in tabularray  there are even more difficult as tabularray wants to see the content to split it into cells).

Generally it is better to simply create boxes. As an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\usepackage[LSBC4, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xskak,chessboard}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC4}%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame
\hidemoves{1.e4 f6 2.d4 g5 3.Qh5#}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\xskaksep{}
 {
  \int_if_zero:nTF {\int_mod:nn {(\xskakget{movenr} - 1) * 2 + (\str_if_eq:eeTF {\xskakget{player}} {w} {1} {2})}{3}}
   { \par }
   { \space }
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xskakloop{%
       \noindent\begin{tabular}{c}
        \chessboard[tinyboard, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
        \\
        \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}%
        \end{tabular}
        \xskaksep
     }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pages 30-31 of `tabularray`'s documentation explain a pertinent difference between `tblr` and `tabular`. `tblr` parses the specification of the tabularray using `l3regex`. As such, `&` and `\\`  must be explicitly present. They cannot be 'hidden'. This means you cannot say

```
\begin{tblr}{ccc}
  \macroholdingspecification
\end{tblr}
```

There are two limited workarounds. One involves defining your macro with `\newcommand*` outside the environment, if no optional arguments are involved. Then you can use `expand=\macrodefinedwithnewcommand` in the optional argument to `tblr` to expand `\macrodefinedwithnewcommand` once.

The other involves using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and `expand=\expanded` to expand everything which can be expanded.

Either way, you end up with

```
\begin{tblr}[expand=\expandablemacro]{ccc}
  \expandablemacro
\end{tblr}
```

But this will only work if the definition of `\expandablemacro` truly is expandable. Unfortunately, that is not true of several of the macros you wish to use.

```
> \xskakloop=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \xskakloop \\xskakloop {}.
l.181 \show\xskakloop
                     
? 
> \chessboard=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \chessboard \\chessboard {}.
l.183 \show\chessboard
```

What this shows is that both `\chessboard` and `\xskakloop` are protected (`\@protected`) and not expandable. So if they are in your definition of `\expandablemacro`, `\expandablemacro` will not be expandable.

Since this is an issue which distinguishes `tblr` from `tabular`, you may want to investigate using such an environment as an alternative.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer is probably the best person to ask what might work best.